# Access database (.mdb) import using heroku/python/django

Tags: python, django, ms-access, heroku

We're creating a web app using python/django, hosted on heroku. Part of the functionality we'd like is the ability for users to upload .mdbs (Access databases) to our site, and then parse them. The server runs linux (so windows solutions won't work), with the restrictions imposed by heroku.

On our local, test server we accomplish this without any problems by using a shell script to create csvs from the mdb, and then using python code to read the csvs. However, this doesn't work once we push to heroku

I've tried using pyodbc, but ran into problems with configuring the driver, even on our testing machines.

Does anyone have any ideas for possible workaround, or has done this successfully in the past? I'd be happy to post any code that might be useful, or give any other information that could be helpful. I'm also open to any solution -- at this point we just need to get it to work

Thank you guys!

Comment: Unfortunately we need to use the .mdbs -- we're parsing data from another company, which exports only in .mdbs. Reading the csvs works no problem, but I think it's the shell scrip/mdbtools that we use to parse the mdbs that break it